# Installing ATG 9.1 on Websphere

Tags: websphere-7, atg

I'm trying to install ATG 9.1 on Websphere 7.0 for a development environment.

The configuration is as follow:

```
VirtualBox 4.1.6
RHEL 5 (via CentOS)
IBM Java 6
```

When I install Websphere 7.0 I am able to start up the application server without issue. I can navigate through the admin console and all works fine.

When I try to install ATG 9.1, selecting Websphere as the application server reports: "Invalid WebSphere install directory specified". I have tried various options for the path to Websphere including:

```
/opt/IBM
/opt/IBM/Websphere/AppServer
/opt/IBM/Websphere/AppServer/profiles/AppServ1
```

I've tried setting the WAS_HOME in the environment, I tried running .../bin/setupCmdLine.sh but still no luck.

Does this have anything to do with the 'A supported operating system was not detected' when installing Websphere? I assume not since Websphere is running fine. I've also un-installed and re-installed Websphere to confirm it is going through fine. Each time the server runs but ATG fails to recognise it.

I've installed all the same components on a Windows environment (with the Windows installers instead of the Linux versions) and had no issues. I've also been able to install ATG on JBoss previously without issue.

Any advice on what I'm doing wrong will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Install WAS7.0 as normal. Once completed, go to /properties and copy ibm-was-version.properties to version.properties and then install ATG 9.1